# How to startX as non-root user inside the rc.local?

Tags: boot, gtk, c++, xserver, openbox

I am trying to start `startx` as non-root user in my Ubuntu-server 16.04(`Linux nanopim1 3.4.113-sun8i #16 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 13 14:15:57 CEST 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`) with `openbox` installed on it.

I tried to put each of these files one-by-ne inside `/rc.local` but didn't work! the only thing that is work is putting `startx` without any addition on `/etc/rc.local` and it starts as root!

```
su -l m -c startx

su -s /bin/bash -c startx m&

su - m -c startx
```

Also I tried another way, I did create a file here: `/etc/systemd/system/autologin.service` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Autologin service

[Service]
Type=fork
user=m
group=m
ExecStart=/usr/bin/startx
TimeoutSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` but didn't work again!!!

Only putting `startx` alone inside `/etc/local` works but it's `root` user that I don't want to be!